# Count Query generation in table-per-type inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, table-per-type

I have a typical TPT scenario (don't ask me why I did TPT, it was probably a silly choice to start with), and I am trying to run a simple Count query on the BASE type. 
given that the count is based on the base type and on a property on the base class, I can't understand why but EF is creating a `COUNT(*)` query by joining all the derived types together.

The classes are something like this:

```
public abstract class StudyCase {
    public DateTime? DateSubmitted { get; protected set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}

public class StudyCaseStandard : StudyCase { 
// ... other stuff
}

public class StudyCaseReview : StudyCase { 
// ... other stuff
}
```

My query is something like this

```
SubmittedCasesCount = _context.Set<StudyCase>().Where(sc => !sc.Deleted).Count(sc => sc.DateSubmitted.HasValue);
```

This is the query generated by EF (there is a third class not shown above but seen in the query):

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM   (SELECT 
            [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
            FROM [dbo].[StudyCases_Exacerbation] AS [Extent1]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id]
            FROM [dbo].[StudyCases_Standard] AS [Extent2]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id]
            FROM [dbo].[StudyCases_Review] AS [Extent3]) AS [UnionAll2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[StudyCases] AS [Extent4] ON [UnionAll2].[Id] = [Extent4].[Id]
        WHERE ([Extent4].[Deleted] <> 1) AND ([Extent4].[DateSubmitted] IS NOT NULL)
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
go
```

As you can see it's doing all `UNION` and `JOIN` while it would be much more efficient (and only necessary) to do a simple count like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS [A1]
FROM [dbo].[StudyCases]
WHERE ([Deleted] <> 1) AND ([DateSubmitted] IS NOT NULL)
```

Any idea how to force EF to generate simpler queries when the properties of the derived classes are not needed or when the return set is a set of the base class only (this may depend on the `abstract` keyword on the base class as well, but EF should be able to materialise a proxy for an abstract class)?

Comment: edit: changed this to an answer for code formatting

Answer (score 2):

What query is produced if you use a select statement to pull only properties from the base class, as below:

```
SubmittedCasesCount = 
    _context
        .Set<StudyCase>()
        .Select(sc => new { Deleted = sc.Deleted, DateSubmitted = sc.DateSubmitted })
        .Where(anon => !anon.Deleted)
        .Count(anon => anon.DateSubmitted.HasValue);
```

Edit:
Sadly the above produces the same query, the only other solution I am aware of is doing a raw SQL query, something like:

```
int count = context.Set<StudyCase>
                   .FromSql("SELECT Deleted, DateSubmitted FROM dbo.StudyCases")
                   .Where(sc => !sc.Deleted).Count(sc => sc.DateSubmitted.HasValue)
                   .Count();
```

Comment: That's a shame, I have edited with another way of achieving this, albeit a somewhat less elegant one.

Comment: A custom query was the direction I did not want to go, although it seems to me the only alternative as well...